# django-import-export: how to specify reference model outside of xls

Tags: django, foreign-keys, inline, django-import-export

i have a model (e.g. book) which has a foreign key to another (e.g. author)
i want to import all book's of an author in one xls file.
is there a way to add a normal django foreign key widget alongside file input and apply the selected key to all of imported rows?

bonus question: is this possible to have an inline (StackedInline?) in reference model (author) which uses import mixin (this one solves the first question inherently, right?)

i tried both with no success. and i can't find anything helpful in the net.
any help would be appreciated.